# how to get a list of users currenltly logged in(Authenticated) to IIS6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-3.5

Need to get a list of currently loggedn in(authenticated)  users from IIS6, and to display them in updatepanel (ajax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS6 does not have any authentication system/module in itself. You need to have a membership provider. In such a case, you might query the provider for the currently logged in users.

Alternatively, if you are using session for keeping the authenticated user, you might ad an Application variable and update it with currently logged in used upon every successful authentication or sign out/session obsolescence.

Let us know, how you are doung the authentication.

Comment: Note: Session expiration event only works with InProcess session storage.

Comment: The ADS is the authenticator, if ADS authenticate then we route the user to appropriate ASP page

Comment: Let me rephrase the Question..
ADS authenticate the user, and request is directed to IIS, IIS Create a session for the user.. Now I want to get to know who the Session user is..

Comment: If you just need to know who the user is, the ADS membership manager does have the details of the user already.